# simply importing tensorflow kills my Jupiter notebook kernel

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

As described in jypyter notebook I tried:

import tensorflow

then my kernel is killed, like "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Tried to reinstall anaconda, numpy, tensorflow, didn't work.

Comment: This kernel died message is very useless, you should import tensorflow in a python shell (not inside jupyter) and this should give you more information about why the kernel crashes.

Comment: Jupyter kernel dies for several reasons, if you are using GPU,update the CUDA and cuDNN as per the Tensorflow version compatibility, and also update the GPU drivers. Try to update the anaconda using `conda update anaconda`. Make sure right version of numpy installed, run commnad `pip install -U numpy`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well I also experienced this normally this can't work because tensorflow is  too big for jupyter notebook though you may try downloading the anaconda navigator if you don't have it already though this may not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).